# Vacuum Fluorescent Display: What are the benefits of an AC filament driver instead of DC?

Tags: ac, dc, driver, display, vacuum-fluorescent

Question is already in the title:
What is/are the benefit(s) of an AC filament driver instead of DC for VFD displays?
It works with DC so why to invest in an AC driver?

Anyone?

Comment: Would you mind altering the title to say "Vacuum Fluorescent Display" instead of "VFD?" I initially thought this was about variable frequency drives for motors.

Comment: @mkeith changed however a little weird. They called VFD's (first found in google - not variable frequency drives) cannot help the confusion.

Comment: Thank you. It will be less confusing to people using this site when they read the title of the question. This site is very popular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filament is also the cathode of the device.

With DC excitation one end has essentially a different DC bias voltage than the other and will result in different emission. This may give uneven illumination or wear out characteristics than when using AC which evens out the bias.

As other posters have commented it is also preferable to provide the DC bias relative to the center tap of the filament or to have a center-tapped AC supply.

Comment: Hai Thanks for the answer. Is ghosting also a result of DC?

Comment: Early in my career we decided to drive the filaments with DC and it worked great...at first.  After about a year+ you could see the gradient across the display.

Comment: @Aaron, that is a clear answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The display is designed for one or the other, so it's important to use the right kind of drive.

- DC drive: DC current through filament introduces a voltage gradient in the filament (cathode).

VFDs designed for DC compensate for the gradient by tilting the filament, so that the higher voltage side is farther away from the anodes and grids. This evens out the brightness.

If your VFD is designed for AC filament and you drive it with DC, this DC cathode gradient will result in one side being brighter than the other.

- AC drive: Effective cathode gradient is equal one side to the other.

Since the cathode effective DC voltage is equal, AC filament VFDs use a non-tilted filament, that is, equal spacing to anodes and grids from one side to the other. Brightness is even side-to-side.

However, there is an AC gradient on the cathode that can result in flickering at the edges, especially if it 'beats' with the display multiplex. This is even worse if one side is at DC and the other AC, using center-tap AC drive helps.

If you have a VFD designed for DC (tilted filament) and you drive it with AC, the display brightness will be uneven.

More about all this here: https://www.noritake-elec.com/technology/general-technical-information/vfd-operation

And here: https://www.futaba.co.jp/en/display/vfdinfo/vinfo_caution.html

As to why AC, it's a holdover from the vacuum-tube days: filament is just another winding on the transformer. So for appliances and such this makes a lot of sense.

For consumer devices, like the DVD player I did many, many years ago, I designed my own display and I chose DC driven from a floating secondary winding from the switching power supply.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. Second paragraph is very informative, "especially flickering at the edges" because I have a display that I thought had some ghosting however after reading your answer I think that is not the issue, a result of. Thanks.